# How do I find Roman Numerals in a string and make it all upper case in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a XML file with multiple roman numerals. I want to take the roman numerals and convert them to uppercase. I have found the numerals using Regex but I don't know how to replace each one with uppercase.

[Input - For Roman Numerals](https://regex101.com/r/tYZTnE/2)

Comment: This question does not show any code, can you provide us with your code? as far as i can tell if you can get the roman numbers in a non sensitive case manner, then you can simply call the .ToUpper() method to the roman number

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/tYZTnE/3) working for you?

Comment: @Toto - It works :)

Comment: Just a small help, if you notice, it is finding empty spaces as well, so the replacement is actually adding \U to every match found. Is there a way to remove the spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Regex.Replace for converting matches to UpperCase. For example,

```
var result= Regex.Replace(text, pattern,c=>c.ToString().ToUpper());
```

Comment: Works perfectly :)